# Access: addressing Excel Range

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am using Access to loop through a data table and generate an Excel Workbook (with three sheets) for each row in the database table. All works very well until I introduce code using "Range" to validate data. (Limiting range to integers).
If I use only one row from the database and run the program the result is successful. If I run that option again without exiting the program I get the error Method 'Cells' of Object '_Global' failed.

I have searched the internet and believe that it NOT possible to reference cells in range with R1C1
The code I am using is :-

```
 wks.Range("B2:H14").Activate
   wks.Range("B2:H14").Select

    With wks.Range("B2:H14").Validation

     .Add Type:=xlValidateWholeNumber, _
     AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1", Formula2:=Cells(1, "E")
     .InputTitle = "Integers"
     .ErrorTitle = "Integers"
     .InputMessage = "Enter an integer "
     .ErrorMessage = "You must use valid number"
    End With
```

My requirements are actually a bit more complex than this (where Formula2 will vary depending on column) but one step at a time.

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Cells needs to be from the excel object to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cells(1, "E")
```

Looks like you're missing a period in front, which means the call to the `Cells` method is unqualified.

Try `wks.Cells(1, "E")` instead which tells the code that the cells belong to the `wks` object.

Comment: Thanks, but that produces an error immediately. Problem lies in selecting range when worksheet hanges